# Is this a valid usage of ``const_cast``?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard has changed the signature of the `erase()` methods of standard containers: they now accept `const_iterator`s instead of `iterator`s. The rationale is explained in this document:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2350.pdf

Now, if one implements `std::vector<T>` in a straightforward way, it is possible to use directly `const T *` and `T *` as const and mutable iterator types respectively. So in the `erase()` method we might have code like this:

```
iterator erase(const_iterator it)
{
    ...
    for (; it != end() - 1; ++it) {
        // Destroy the current element.
        it->~T();
        // Move-init the current iterator content with the next element.
        ::new (static_cast<void *>(it)) T(std::move(*(it + 1))); // FAIL
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem now is that, since `it` is a const pointer, the static cast will fail.

Is it legal in this case to cast away the constness from `it`? Note that `it` never points to a `const` object (the objects stored in the vector are never `const`), and that the calling method (`erase()`) is not `const` as well.

**EDIT**: thanks for all the replies. I wanted to respond here to some comments below.

This code comes from a custom vector class (with a similar interface to `std::vector`) that implements the small buffer optimisation on top of an unrestricted union. The iterators are naked pointers because they need to be the same type both when the vector is using static storage and when it is using dynamic storage, and this seems the most natural way of achieving such result.

The cast to `void *` is just a matter of habit and consistency within the codebase when interacting with unitialised storage.

Comment: Aside: I'm a little puzzled by the implementation, you will destruct *it, then reinitialize it with *(it+1) passed as an rvalue, which leaves *(it + 1) in a destructible state, often by having swapped or memberwise-swapped values from *(it) into *(it + 1). Then you destruct *(it+1) which is empty/destructed from the initial it->~T().  It seems you could either do the initial destruct before the loop or you could just not bother invoking the destructor and so that *(it) is essentially shuffled to the end of the container and then destructed when the container drops the last element.

Comment: Just wondering why would you be static casting to void *

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `allocator_traits` to copy and move elements, and not hardcode in-place destruction and placement news?

Comment: A `std::vector`'s iterator type should not sport a conversion to `void*`.

Comment: @kfsone Yes good points. I am not too concerned about the performance of the erase operation at the moment and was more preoccupied about the const vs nonconst semantics.

Comment: @Kam it's just a habit I picked up when interacting with unitialised storage. The memory in this specific case is coming from a ``std::aligned_storage``.

Comment: @BenVoigt see edits. In this custom vector class the memory can be coming either from the stack or from the heap, depending on runtime conditions. It is not a full drop-in replacement for ``std::vector``, just something with a subset of the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `erase` is non-const, yes, you can safely cast away const on the element. However, note that this is not necessary, since a non-const iterator can be obtained from the const iterator:

```
iterator non_const = begin() + (it - begin());
```

And that can be used to iterate over the vector.

Comment: I had thought about this, but I am trying to avoid a much as possible pointer differences. The switching back and forth to/from signed/unsigned integrals always irks me.

Comment: @bluescarni: There is no switching back and forth between signed/unsigned. The result of a pointer subtraction is `std::ptrdiff_t`, a signed type. And when an integer is added to a pointer, it is promoted to `std::ptrdiff_t`. So there are no unsigned integers in this statement. Likewise, for standard library iterators, the result of a subtraction is of type `iterator::difference_type`, which is always a signed type, usually a typedef for `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the fact that adding an integral value to a pointer results in the integral value being promoted? I am looking at 5.7/5 (C++11) and it does not say anything about it. 5.7/6 mentions ptrdiff_t regarding the difference between pointers.

Comment: @bluescarni: 13.6/13 shows the built-in operators for pointer arithmetic. They all expect `std::ptrdiff_t` for the integer.

Comment: Thanks! So basically it's impossible to reach the end of big enough arrays with pointer-integral operations in constant time? I am also surprised that GCC and Clang do not warn about potentially unsafe conversion, e.g., when adding a ``size_t`` to a pointer...